# Is there a way to run VMWare VMs faster than normal?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I run a ton of blackbox tests that have code that look something like this:

```
Do something
Wait 30 seconds or so for something to expire from the cache
Do something else
Etc...
```

Since the tests are all self contained in their own universe, I would like some way to speed up the time on those system. Think of it like "Narnia Time". That is to say, a "sleep 30 seconds" on this VM might execute in 10 seconds in the real world. So if I'm a program on the VM, it certainly feels like 30 seconds, but only because the VM runs with a different rate of time.

Is what I'm asking for possible? If so, how do I do it and what should I be googling to learn more?

Comment: I don't know if this even makes sense or is possible, but here you go. Maybe you could tie an internal time-server to a fixed amount of ticks and then increase the amount of ticks called(?) per second. [link](https://superuser.com/a/101202/915696)

Comment: So for those who all downvoted this, can you provide some feedback? Was the question worded bad? Is this the wrong stack exchange to ask such a question?